# How do I protect myself from ARP spoofing as a client?

Tags: arp-spoofing

Network topology:

```
Public AP <-WiFi-> Raspberry Pi (NAT #1) <-Ethernet-> WiFi AP (NAT #2) <-WiFi-> Clients
```

Situation: I'm connecting to a dormitory access point that's shared with a lot of other people. When the going gets tough, I do an ARP-spoof attack on the network using an Android app called "NetCut", or `wifikill`/`netcut` on Linux.

Lately, I've noticed someone else has apparently learned how to do such an attack.

As a client, with no access to the router (but root access on my own Linux machine), how do I circumvent an ARP spoof done by someone greedy?

---

Possible (but not applicable) duplicates:

- Admin access to router: [How to figure out that someone is ARP spoofing me and what to do against it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/90900/70515)
- This admin has full access to their router: [arp spoofing protection on LAN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20147/arp-spoofing-protection-on-lan)
- Possibly outdated information: [How to tell if you're being ARP poisoned?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29982/70515)
- Does not seem applicable: [How should this system be protected from ARP spoofing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/34879/70515)
- Describes attack, not defense: [Arp Spoofing Causing Dropped Connections](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/81345/70515)
- Describes attack, not defense: [ARP poisoning attack consequences](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/154595/70515)
- Windows: [How to prevent an arp poisoning attack (from the client's POV)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150670/70515)

Answer (score 1):

You could disable ARP completely:
(assuming your network device is `eth0`)
`ip link set dev eth0 arp off`
Then, you will need to manually add static ARP entities to any host you want to talk to using the `arp` command.

However, the attacker could still spoof your address, such that the gateway or other hosts thinks that the attacker is you.